# Why Httpclient only get the 202 but browser could get back the image content

Tags: java, httpclient

I want to get the validation code from image, but I can't get the image download with Httpclient getMethord. HttpClient get the status code 202, howeber the browser could get back the image.

I use the Httpclient verion 4.5.8 Jar.

```
String url = "https://wbca.cde.org.cn/wbca/jcaptcha";
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);

  try {
      HttpResponse response;
      response = httpClient.execute(getMethod, new BasicHttpContext());
      System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

      HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
      InputStream instream = entity.getContent(); 
      OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\123.jpg"));
      int l = -1;
      byte[] tmp = new byte[2048]; 
      while ((l = instream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
          outstream.write(tmp);
      } 
      outstream.close();
  }  catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
      getMethod.releaseConnection();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content returned from the set URL "https://wbca.cde.org.cn/wbca/jcaptcha" is not an image file, but rather HTML page (forming the image on browser using javascript). See the response headers:

```
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Date: Fri, 19 Apr 2019 08:32:43 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: ******
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 19 Apr 2019 08:28:55 GMT
```

Comment: yes, that is the contents in the reponsebody. If that, is there a way to generate the Image by Java or JS?   Actually this is the validation code image, if server return the script to form the image, the code should be encripted from the script?

Comment: You need to duplicate browser's capability within your Java program in order to execute the downloaded script. This is not an easy task, consider something like Rhino ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino )

Comment: If you check the F12, you could see the Response headers are usual like content returned. If that is second response from  JS request?

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 19 Apr 2019 09:00:40 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: ******